# How to set kubernetes probes for react app?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

Currently I started to use a kubernetes environment to deploy a react app. One thing that should be set are the healthiness and readiness probes. How should they look like for a react app, or are probes used for frontend apps?

Comment: Every app in kubernetes (frontend and backend) must have healthcheck probes.  From Kubernetes perspective successful health check means that application is ready to serve requests.

Comment: Ok, but for backend services usually a healthcheck api is defined. For a frontend app is it enough to make an http request toward the homepage for both probes?

Comment: Generally no, it's not ok, because loading home page generally may take a lot of time and resources. You should create special tiny endpoint that shows you app health status - ok or not ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a separate pod for your front end, I assume a Web server like Apache or Nginx, the health check would just make sure the Webserver is alive. So you are correct that this would be a simple request, f.e. to the home page which is just static html. 
For the backend a different check would be in order. 
If you have just a single pod you need to check both with a health check.

Answer (score 1):

If you can expose services, you should add a simple API with a fast response for the health check like:

```
app.get('/health-check',(req,res)=> {
  res.send ("OK");
});
```

use this in your readiness probe.

Otherwise you could use a TCP readiness and liveness probe on the exposed port and the same on a startup probe with a greater failureThreshold time.
You may also use the startup probe on the index file, or to check the correctness of the directories structure.

Here you can find the relative docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: Your answer makes assumptions about the technology of the backend and explains backend probes while the question is targeted at a react frontend application.

Comment: My answer was taking care of different solutions depending on the use case, I have made it more explicit. Still better than reading an index file thousand times a day * the number of pods, for a readiness probe :)